# Copy JSON from console.log in developer tool to clipboard?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, json

Using Chrome Developer Tools, i have printed a JSON object with `console.log`.

is there a way that I can copy it to the clipboard?

Comment: change `console.log(myObj)` to `copy(myObj)` (see [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#copy))

Answer (score 405, accepted):

If the right-click -> copy is not available you could try:

1 - Right-click the object and select "Store as global variable"

2 - The console will print the new variable's name, for example:

```
//temp1
```

3 - Type:

```
copy(temp1)
```

The object is now available in your clipboard.

Tested in chrome 36

Comment: In Chrome 41 this returns `undefined`.

Comment: @isherwood I've jsut tested in Chrome 41 and still works, you might be missing something.

Comment: what do you mean by " Right-click the object" ?

Comment: @EdwinSnts Bertrand means in the Javascript console, after logging an object with `console.log( myObject )`, to right click on that object. It will give you a context menu with the "Store as global variable" feature.

Comment: `copy(temp1)` works in Chrome 46, but copying a larger object (a jQuery.Event object), the clipboard gets `[object Object]`.

Comment: In Chrome `copy(temp1)` returns `undefined` but the object is available in your clipboard.

Comment: Does this work programatically too, or only through the console? (e.g forcing content on the user's clipboard)

Comment: Also, make sure <top frame> is selected or Store as Global Variable won't work.

Comment: @Johannes seems to work programaticaly for me

Comment: This is the best way to capture the JSON from console. Is there a Chrome extension that does this and downloads to a log file?

Comment: @sealocal: Yes, I also experienced this with a large object. Kind of irritating, because it is speacially on large objects this would be useful.

Comment: So simple, I had no idea.  Love it!

Comment: Link to docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#copy

Comment: `copy(myVariable)` even has it pretty-printed. Awesome!

Comment: @sealocal I was getting vexed about this too, but it turns out it does that [Object object] thing if the object has any recursive parts. In the console do a={b:4} then a.c=a and then copy(a) and try to paste. I ended up deleting portions of the object.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple method...from the console surround the json with JSON.stringify(yourobjecthere).  Then highlight the text or optionally select the Copy button in the developer bar if it exceeds X number of rows.  Hope this helps someone.

Example:

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(window.atob(localStorage.getItem('C_C_M'))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @Bertrand works.But it won't when there is already an element by name **copy** in the Dom.

Doing copy(temp1) gave me **Uncaught TypeError: copy is not a function**

So I removed that element from the Dom in my console using the below line:
**document.querySelector('#copy').remove()**

Now copy(temp1) works!

Comment: Thanks, this worked when nothing else on the internet did. This should be the real answer.

Comment: This is the solution when you've opened a terminal on a random website to play with an object :D

Answer (score 0):

Select the text in the console, then use right click -> copy

To copy the entire log (when I needed): hit ctrl-a (select all) then ctrl-c (copy)

Note: Since posting this I noticed sometimes it is necessary to select a little text before these steps work. Also for a long console output scroll to the top of the console and select a little text first. Grrr... still this is easier than saving as a file.

== Above is using Chrome 35 ==

Comment: Doesn't work for me—it just copies the collapsed summary of the variable.